# Why can’t I redownload Minecraft when I deleted it

Tags: mac, applications, mac-appstore

I paid for Minecraft on the App Store. I accidentally deleted it and now I can’t get it back. I signed into all 3 of my accounts but it always says minecraft costs money. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Some reasons why this could be.

You changed your country or region:

> If you previously changed the country or region of your Apple ID, you might not see all of your past purchases.

Also try:

> If you can't find an item that you want to redownload, check your purchase history to make sure that you purchased it with the Apple ID that you're signed in with. If not, sign in with a different Apple ID.

Your purchases could be hidden:

> If you don't see items in your 
>   purchase history on other Apple IDs, 
>   check to see if the purchases are 
>   hidden. If your purchases are hidden, 
>   you might not see them even after you 
>   follow the steps in this article.

Additionally if the purchase was part 
of a Family Sharing group and you 
have been removed from it you can’t 
re-download it.

Comment: Sorry, it didn’t work and I’m pretty sure it’s not hidden.

Answer (score -2):

I believe that the App Store nor Mojang are aware if you delete Minecraft, therefore if you try to download it again - and they do not know that you had it already - they will try to charge you. If you try to tell them (either Mojang or App Store) that, they will probably charge you anyway because they will (both) do whatever they can to make themselves money. Hope this helps.

Comment: (Mojang is the team working on Minecraft and the people who create the updates and all that)